# ndk-build outputs ‘error adding symbols. File in wrong format’

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, exiv2

I want to use the exiv2 library written in C++ in my Android project. To do that, I try to cross-compile the library using the Android NDK.

For cross-compiling, I follow the presented below steps:

1. Add the NDK path to variable PATH

   ```
   PATH="/home/patrycja/android-packages/ndk:${PATH}"
   export PATH
   ```
2. Install the standard toolchain for cross-compiling C/C++ for Android.

   ```
   ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain --ndk-dir='/home/patrycja/android-packages/ndk/' --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --system=linux-x86_64
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   Copying prebuilt binaries...
   Copying sysroot headers and libraries...
   Copying c++ runtime headers and libraries...
   Copying files to: /tmp/my-android-toolchain
   Cleaning up...
   Done.
   ```
3. Set some environment variables so that the configuration and build process will use the right compiler.

   ```
   export PATH=/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin:$PATH
   export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"
   export CXX="arm-linux-androideabi-g++"
   export CFLAGS='-mthumb -O2'
   export CXXFLAGS='-mthumb -O2'
   export LDFLAGS='-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8'
   export LIBS='-lstdc++ -lsupc++'
   ```
4. Build the static library and sufficient headers

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/build --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-shared --disable-xmp --disable-nls
   ```

As a result, I have created ‘build’ category files:

```
    ├── bin
    │   └── exiv2
    ├── include
    │   └── exiv2
    │       ├── *.hpp
    │
    ├── lib
    │   ├── libexiv2.a
    │   ├── libexiv2.la
    │   └── pkgconfig
    │       └── exiv2.pc
    └── share
        └── man
            └── man1
                └── exiv2.1
```

I copied the created static library `libexiv2.a` and `include` folder to my Android project in `appName/src/main/jni/prebuild`.

`Android.mk` looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Static library information
LOCAL_MODULE := exiv2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libexiv2.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include/
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# Wrapper information
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../prebuild/include/
LOCAL_MODULE    := helloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloJNI.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := exiv2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

In my wrapper in Android, I try to use the library. It looks like as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <exiv2/exiv2.hpp>

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_patrycja_testndi2_MyActivity_helloJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        std::string file("/storage/emmc/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0021.jpg");
        Exiv2::Image::AutoPtr image = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(file);
        return env->NewStringUTF("asldjaljd");
    }
}
```

However `ndk-build` outputs that it can’t find it.

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : helloJNI &lt;= helloJNI.cpp
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libhelloJNI.so
jni/../prebuild/libexiv2.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libhelloJNI.so] Error 1
```

I believe that there’s something wrong with flags in cross-compiling. I have tried several options, but something is still wrong.

I’ve followed these instructions: *[How to use an external C++ library from native Android code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/mYh1LzMu_0U)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've compiled exiv2 for *armv5+* devices running at least *[Android 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Lollipop)* (Lollipop). Here ndk-build fails, because it's trying to link it from an arm64-v8a library it's building.

Cross-compiling without using ndk-build is hard to get right on Android, especially as you should support not only armv5, but also armv7, x86, x86_64, arm64-v8a, etc.

You should first set the `--platform` option to the same level as your minimum SDK level. Then rebuild your library and place it under `../prebuild/armeabi`.

Then also cross-compile your library for the x86 architecture:

```
./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain-x86 --ndk-dir='/home/patrycja/android-packages/ndk/' --arch=x86 --toolchain=x86-4.8 --system=linux-x86_64

export PATH=/tmp/my-android-toolchain-x86/bin:$PATH
export CC="i686-linux-android-gcc"
export CXX="i686-linux-android-g++"
export CFLAGS='-O2 -mtune=atom -mssse3 -mfpmath=sse'
export CXXFLAGS='-O2 -mtune=atom -mssse3 -mfpmath=sse'
export LDFLAGS=''
export LIBS='-lstdc++ -lsupc++'

./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/build-x86 --host=x86 --disable-shared --disable-xmp --disable-nls
```

And move the created .a to `../prebuild/x86`.

Ideally, you should repeat the same process also for armeabi-v7a, mips, mips64, and arm64-v8a.

Finally, you can include the right .a inside your *Android.mk* using the `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` variable, like so:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Static library information
LOCAL_MODULE := exiv2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libexiv2.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include/
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# Wrapper information
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../prebuild/include/
LOCAL_MODULE    := helloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloJNI.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := exiv2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And inside *Application.mk* (create a new file if it doesn't exist), specify the architectures you're supporting and the minimum platform you're targeting:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi x86 # Ideally, this should be set to "all"
APP_PLATFORM := android-14 # Should be the same as -platform and your minSdkVersion.
```

Comment: I did like you said, but another problem occured. Doing ndk-build I receive: `jni/../prebuild/armeabi-v7a/libexiv2.a(pngchunk.o):pngchunk.cpp:function Exiv2::Internal::PngChunk::parseChunkContent(Exiv2::Image*, unsigned char const*, long, Exiv2::DataBuf): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'`

Comment: I have used wrong version of gcc. It works with 4.8.

Comment: This solution presumes the legacy ndk gradle build.  With the new gradle-experimental build system, there is no **Application.mk**.

Comment: the original question was about ndk-build so the answer is still accurate. If you have the same kind of issue with gradle and the experimental plugin, you should open a new question.